# How do closures in Scheme work?

Tags: lambda, scope, scheme, closures

I tested the following code in Racket/DrScheme:

```
(define (makem)
    (define x 34)
    (list (lambda () (set! x (+ x 1)) x)
          (lambda () (set! x (+ x 1)) x))
)

(define f (car (makem)))
(define f2 (car (cdr (makem))))

> (f)
35
> (f2)
35            ; I thought this would give me 36
> (f)
36
> (f)
37
>
```

Does every lambda created inside a function call get a copy of every variable in their scope? Is it like some sort of implicit let? I expected the lambdas to have some sort o pointer to the scope in which they were created, enabling them to access the stack variables, but this tells me otherwise, since f and f2 seem to have different copies of x. What exactly happens?

Comment: You should _really_ go read [chapter 3 of SICP.](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-21.html#%_sec_3.2)  I was mystified until I read it, and then it made the whole process perfectly clear.  See in particular 3.2.3, "frames as the repository of local state."  (Short answer: yes, it's kind of like an implicit `let`, and they have different copies of `x`.)

Comment: Also in SICP, take a look at applicative-order vs normal-order. That'll explain why both functions in your list set x to be 35.

Comment: @mquander: They only have different copies of `x` because they are coming from  different copies of `(makem)`. If they were actually the two elements of one call to `(makem)`, rather than the first element of one call and the second element of a different call, then they would have the same copy of `x`.

Comment: @dfan: Yep, that's true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You called `(makem)` twice, so you created two different environments with two different copies of `x`. If you called `(makem)` once, like so:

```
(define m (makem))
(define f (car m))
(define f2 (car (cdr m)))
```

then `f` and `f2` would indeed share the same `x`, the one in `m`.

Comment: d'oh! now it did what I expected. one must be careful when evaluating things twice. I already knew that since before starting on lisp, such a stupid mistake!!